# Recalculating exponentially smoothed value with different smoothing parameters.

Tags: exponential-function

I have a time series and I cannot keep all the data.

I want to do exponential smoothing to get a single smoothed result:
$$y_{a,t} = \sum_{i=0}^t {x_{t-i}*a^i}$$

In future I might need $y_{a,t}$ with **different** values of the smoothing factor $a$.

I want to calculate some fixed number of values that would allow me to approximate $y_{a}$ for any $a \in [0, 1]$ with least amount of error.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Should I just calculate $y_{a_k}$ for several values of $a_k$ (e.g. for $a_k = k/n$ where $n=10, k=0..n$) and do linear/quadratic interpolation?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking, but, it may be of use to note that exponential smoothing can usually be done without saving data. For example, define $z_0=x_0$ and $z_{t+1} = z_t(1-\theta) + \theta x_t$ for $t \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\}$.  Then you can show, for all $t \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\}$, $$z_t = (1-\theta)^{t+1}x_0 +  \theta \sum_{k=0}^t (1-\theta)^kx_{t-k} $$ and so $$\sum_{k=0}^t (1-\theta)^kx_{t-k} = \frac{z_t-(1-\theta)^{t+1}x_0}{\theta}$$

Comment: @Michael Ok. You've calculated $z_t$. Now let's calculate $z_{\theta_2,t}$ for $\theta_2$ without the original data ($x_t$)

Comment: Now I understand what you are asking, which seems more difficult.  By the way, this reminds me of "fast Fourier transform" and "fast z-transform" methods, and recent results (in the past few years) have been developed on that.

Comment: A hybrid version of your discretization idea might be to observe that the dominant terms in the sum are the last ones, so, keep track of the past $m$ values of the data $x_i$, where $m$ is as large as you can store in memory, then approximate the error $\sum_{i=m}^{t} x_{t-i}a^i$ by keeping a vector of these values for $\hat{a} \in [0, \delta, 2\delta, ..., 1]$, (or use non-uniform sampling with smaller intervals when $\hat{a}$ is close to 1).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an error-analysis of a nonuniform sampling scheme, which also shows how many samples are needed to ensure an error of at most $\delta>0$.

#### Main result

Assume data is bounded so that there is a constant $c>0$ such that $|x_i|\leq c$ for all $i \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\}$. Fix $\rho \in [0,1)$.  Assume $a \in [0, \rho]$. Fix $\delta>0$. We show that error can be bounded by $\delta$ (for all iterations $t$) using a number of samples $r$ given by: 
$$ \boxed{r = \left\lceil \frac{(c/\delta)\rho}{1-\rho}\right\rceil} $$

#### Discretization

Let $\{a_k\}_{k=0}^{\infty}$ be a sequence such that
$$0=a_0 < a_1 < a_2 < ... < 1 $$ 
We shall keep exponential averages for $a_0, ..., a_r$, where $\rho\leq a_r<1$. (We can efficiently implement this using the recursive scheme in my first comment above). We shall choose the $a_k$ values appropriately (with nonuniform spacing) to ensure the error is always at most $\delta$, then see how many samples $r$ are needed to ensure $a_r\geq \rho$ (so we can handle the entire interval $[0,\rho]$).

#### Error for $a \in [a_{k-1}, a_k)$

Suppose $a \in [a_{k-1}, a_k)$ for some $k \in \{1, 2, ...\}$. The error between using weight $a_{k-1}$ and weight $a$ over $t$ iterations is: 
\begin{align}
\left|\sum_{i=0}^t a^i x_{t-i} - \sum_{i=0}^t a_{k-1}^i x_{t-i} \right| &=\left|\sum_{i=0}^t (a^i-a_{k-1}^i)x_{t-i}\right| \\
&\leq \sum_{i=0}^t |x_{t-i}|(a^i - a_{k-1}^i) \\
&\leq c\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (a_k^i - a_{k-1}^i)\\
&= \frac{c}{1-a_k} - \frac{c}{1-a_{k-1}} \\
&= \frac{c(a_k-a_{k-1})}{(1-a_{k-1})(1-a_k)} 
\end{align}
Fix $\delta>0$. Knowing $a_{k-1}$, we now choose $a_k >a_{k-1}$ to ensure the error is at most $\delta$.  We need: 
$$ \frac{c (a_k-a_{k-1})}{(1-a_{k-1})(1-a_k)} = \delta \quad (Eq. 1)$$
So $a_k  = a_{k-1} + (\delta/c)(1-a_{k-1})(1-a_k)$.  This yields: 
$$ a_k = \frac{a_{k-1} + (\delta/c)(1-a_{k-1})}{1+(\delta/c)(1-a_{k-1})}$$
and it holds that $a_{k-1} < a_k < 1$.

#### Number of samples needed

How many samples $r$ are needed to ensure $a_r\geq \rho$? 
Define $z_k = 1-a_k$ for $k \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\}$, so $1=z_0>z_1>z_2>...> 0$. Equation 1 implies:
\begin{align}
&\frac{c(z_{k-1} - z_k)}{z_{k-1}z_k} =  \delta  \\
&\implies \boxed{z_k = \frac{z_{k-1}}{1+(\delta/c) z_{k-1}} \quad \forall k \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\}}
\end{align}

Claim:  The above iteration yields: 
$$ z_k = \frac{(c/\delta)}{k + (c/\delta)}\quad , \forall k \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\}$$

Proof: We use induction.  It holds for $z_{k-1}$ with $k-1=0$ since $z_0=1$. Suppose it is true for some $k-1\geq 0$. We prove it holds for $k$. Then: 
\begin{align}
z_k &= \frac{z_{k-1}}{1 + (\delta/c)z_{k-1}} \\
&= \frac{\frac{(c/\delta)}{k-1+ (c/\delta)}}{1 + \frac{1}{k-1 + (c/\delta)}}\\
&= \frac{c/\delta}{k + (c/\delta)} 
\end{align}
$\Box$

So we just use $r$ samples, where $r$ is the smallest integer such that: 
\begin{align}
\frac{(c/\delta)}{r + (c/\delta)} \leq 1-\rho
\implies r = \left\lceil \frac{(c/\delta)\rho}{1-\rho}\right\rceil
\end{align}

In view of the above equality for $z_k$, it holds that
$$ \boxed{a_k = 1 - \frac{(c/\delta)}{k + (c/\delta)} \quad, \forall k \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\}} $$

Comment: As in my comments above, the hybrid scheme that keeps a memory of the $m$ most recent data points $x_t, x_{t-1}, ..., x_{t-(m-1)}$ and then uses this type of nonuniform discretization to estimate $\sum_{i=m}^t a^i x_{t-i}$ would do even better, and its error can be analyzed similarly.

Comment: Thinking more, I think I can improve the $O(1/\delta)$ number of samples given above to $O(\sqrt{1/\delta})$ with a simple modification.  By the way Ark-kun, what is the context of this question?  Why do you want to solve that problem?

Comment: The application is almost direct. I have user data time series (say, #clicks over time) and I want to get decayed values, but I do not know the best decay factor yet. and I do not want to retain all non-aggregated data. So, I want to store multiple values and be able to emulate any decay. There can also be cases where the optimal decay might be a function of current state of the system, so there needs to be a way to adjust it.